# NCreport (2.20.3) QGraphics View size adjustment

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am displaying my QChartView (QT Creator 5.8) via the ncreport (2.20.3), but unfortunately the size seems small and nonadjustable, I pretty new for this QtCreator c++ programming although I've tried my best to do research on it but still confusing with its coding, anyone can provides me the links if possible on how to understand the basic of this c++ programming language effectively, below is my code and output for your reference. Appreciate for any related links or code on solving this issues.

```
NCReport * report = new NCReport();
Graph *graph = new Graph();
report->reset(true);

//pie display
QPieSeries *series = new QPieSeries();
series->append("Jane", 1);
series->append("Joe", 2);
series->append("Andy", 3);
series->append("Barbara", 4);
series->append("Axel", 5);

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);

QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);

chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

//chart display
QLineSeries* lineseries1 = new QLineSeries();
    lineseries1->setName("my Trend Line");
    lineseries1->append(0, 6);
    lineseries1->append(2, 4);
    lineseries1->append(3, 8);
    lineseries1->append(7, 4);
    lineseries1->append(10, 5);
    *lineseries1 << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);

//bar chart series
QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Jane");
QBarSet *set1 = new QBarSet("John");
QBarSet *set2 = new QBarSet("Axel");
QBarSet *set3 = new QBarSet("Mary");
QBarSet *set4 = new QBarSet("Sam");

   *set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6;
   *set1 << 5 << 0 << 0 << 4 << 0 << 7;
   *set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 8 << 5;
   *set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5;
   *set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2;

QBarSeries *barseries =  new QBarSeries();
   barseries->append(set0);
   barseries->append(set1);
   barseries->append(set2);
   barseries->append(set3);
   barseries->append(set4);

QChart *chart1 = new QChart();
    //chart1->legend()->show();
    chart1->addSeries(lineseries1);
    chart1->addSeries(barseries);
    chart1->createDefaultAxes();
    chart1->setTitle("Simple line and bar chart example");

//set the axes
QStringList categories;
  categories << "Jan" << "Feb" << "Mar" << "Apr" << "May" << "Jun" ;

QBarCategoryAxis *axisX = new QBarCategoryAxis();
  axisX->append(categories);
  chart1->setAxisX(axisX,lineseries1);
  chart1->setAxisX(axisX,barseries);
  axisX->setRange(QString("Jan"), QString("Jun"));

QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis();
  chart1->setAxisY(axisY,lineseries1);
  chart1->setAxisY(axisY,barseries);
  axisY->setRange(0,11);
  chart1->legend()->setVisible(true);
  chart1->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

QChartView *chartView1 = new QChartView(chart1);
   chartView1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

   report->reportDef()->addGraphicsView("pie01", chartView );
   report->reportDef()->addGraphicsView("line01", chartView1 );

   report->setReportFile("://reports/ncreport/myReport.xml");
   report->runReportToPreview();

if ( !report->hasError() ) {

          NCReportPreviewWindow * pv = new NCReportPreviewWindow();

          pv->setOutput( (NCReportPreviewOutput * )report->output() );
          pv->setWindowModality( Qt::ApplicationModal );
          pv->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
          pv->setReport( report ); // sets the report objects
          pv->exec();

          } else {

              QMessageBox msgBox;
              msgBox.setText(QObject::tr("Report error: ") + report->lastErrorMsg());
              msgBox.exec();
              QMessageBox::warning(0,"", tr("Error"));

  }

 delete report;
```

[image]

Comment: You could share the file `myReport.xml`

Comment: [myReport.xml attached here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmL4_TPO8-MBhSiwVSliLDl0cUiQ)